# Python: divide an array into section

Tags: python, json

**Update: I managed to fix the issue with the help of Jeremy's function that break my data set in to 50 chunks. I have posted the final answer.**

I have the following code the reason I want to break the array into chunks is that I am trying to use an api that only allows 50 requests at a time. Also I am java developer who is trying to move to python. What I want to do is break the array into 50 chunks and feed them to the api.

I have a text file that has long list of Ids, I and based on the Id that i read in I am constructing the URL.

```
import simplejson as json
import sys
import urllib
import traceback, csv, string

# "base" API URL
URL_BASE = 'Some URL'
# set user agent string
urllib.version = "Data Collection Fix it"

page_ids = []

def divide_list(list_, n):
    for i in range(0, len(list_), n):
        yield list_[i:i + n]

def issue_query():

    iFile = open('ReadFromThisFile.txt', "r")
    lines = iFile.readlines()
    #print len(lines)

    for line in lines:
        ids = string.split(line)
        ids = ids[0]
        page_ids.append(ids)            

    url = URL_BASE
    indicies = range(len(page_ids))
    File = open("WriteToThisFile.csv", "w")
    for indicies in divide_list(page_ids, 50):
        count = 0
        fiftyIds =[]
        url = URL_BASE
        for id in indicies:
            str(id).strip
            url += str(id) + '|'
            print url
            fiftyIds.append(str(id))
            count += 1
        print count 
        rv = urllib.urlopen(url)
        j = rv.read().decode("utf-8")
        #sys.stderr.write(j + "\n")
        data = json.loads(j)
        for id in fiftyIds:
            try:
                s = int(data["query"]["pages"][id]["revisions"][0]["size"])
                sys.stderr.write("%d\t%d\n" % (int(id), s))
                File.write("%d\t%d\n" % (int(id), s))
                #print ("%d\t%d\n" % (int(id), s))
                # do something interesting with id and s
            except Exception, e:
                traceback.print_exc()

    File.close()
    iFile.close()

issue_query()
```

I know many experience python developers might give me negative points for asking a simple question like this but I couldn't find any good examples on google or here. So sorry for any trouble if in case I have repeated a question.

Thanks,

Comment: Why would Perl developers care about your Python abilities? ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: In Python a list is a list, and an array is this : (http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess instead of updating my original post of the question I should have done the answer question. Hopefully its not confusing, I have put updated comment on the question section informing that the issue has been solved and here how I solved it with the help of Jeremy Banks function

```
import simplejson as json
import sys
import urllib
import traceback, csv, string

# "base" API URL
URL_BASE = 'Some URL'
# set user agent string
urllib.version = "Data Collection Fix it"

page_ids = []

def divide_list(list_, n):
    for i in range(0, len(list_), n):
        yield list_[i:i + n]

def issue_query():

    iFile = open('ReadFromThisFile.txt', "r")
    lines = iFile.readlines()
    #print len(lines)

    for line in lines:
        ids = string.split(line)
        ids = ids[0]
        page_ids.append(ids)            

    url = URL_BASE
    indicies = range(len(page_ids))
    File = open("WriteToThisFile.csv", "w")
    for indicies in divide_list(page_ids, 50):
        count = 0
        fiftyIds =[]
        url = URL_BASE
        for id in indicies:
            str(id).strip
            url += str(id) + '|'
            print url
            fiftyIds.append(str(id))
            count += 1
        print count 
        rv = urllib.urlopen(url)
        j = rv.read().decode("utf-8")
        #sys.stderr.write(j + "\n")
        data = json.loads(j)
        for id in fiftyIds:
            try:
                s = int(data["query"]["pages"][id]["revisions"][0]["size"])
                sys.stderr.write("%d\t%d\n" % (int(id), s))
                File.write("%d\t%d\n" % (int(id), s))
                #print ("%d\t%d\n" % (int(id), s))
                # do something interesting with id and s
            except Exception, e:
                traceback.print_exc()

    File.close()
    iFile.close()

issue_query()
```

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a built-in function to do this but I can't think of it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

def divide_list(list_, n):
    """Produces an iterator over subsections of maximum length n of the list."""

    for i in range(0, len(list_), n):
        yield list_[i:i + n]
```

Example usage:

```
print(list(divide_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 3)))
# prints: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

Using it to produce URLs as in your example:

```
BASE_URL = "http://example.com/blah?ids="
page_ids = range(0, 123)

for indices in divide_list(page_ids, 50):
    url = URL_BASE + "|".join(str(i).strip() for i in indices)
    # then do something with url...
    print(url)

# prints:
# http://example.com/blah?ids=0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49
# http://example.com/blah?ids=50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99
# http://example.com/blah?ids=100|101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|109|110|111|112|113|114|115|116|117|118|119|120|121|122
```

Comment: Thanks, so in this case how would i iterate over results each element of array in results?

Comment: I have expanded the example to URLs in the format of your example. Is this clear?

Comment: Sorry I should have added my entire code here, But I did added, I am planning to use your example. The way I plan to use is that once I read it from file to the list I ll pass that list to the method you explain and use return list to iterate. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jeremy I have updated the code and I used your method but looks like I am still doing something wrong. I did the loop little different since its much easier for me to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but don't worry I managed to fix the problem and I have pasted the code which works and spits out exactly what I want in my csv file.

Answer (score 3):

Generator version of [Jeremy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386844/python-divide-an-array-into-section/5386914#5386914):

```
def divide_list(list_, n):

   for i in range(0, len(list_), n):
       yield list_[i:i + n]


for chunk in divide_list([1,2,3,4,5], 2):
   print chunk
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a recipe in the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) (which is really worth a read-through, just so you know what is there for when you need it -- and you *will* need it).

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```